# Ошибка "adoquery1 dataset not in edit or insert mode"

Tags: delphi

Сохраняю таблицу в БД, а выдает ошибку

> adoquery dataset not in edit or insert mode

Код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 try
  ADOQuery1.Active:=True;
     ADOQuery1.Post;
       except
        on e:Exception do  end;end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Примеры посмотрите, в хэлпе тоже есть:

```
ADOQuery1.Active:=True;
ADOQuery1.Edit;//ADOQuery1.Insert;
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('MyField').AsString:='My Value';
ADOQuery1.Post;
```

Comment: что к примеру должно быть вместо этого? 'MyField''My Value'

Comment: Поле и его значение. Вы изменяете текущую запись (или добавляете новую), указываете значения полей, затем делаете Post. Запись (если ошибок нет) будет записана в базу.